# Затирается HTML

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

При попытке сделать манипуляцию на подобии
    $('.gTable').append($("#tt6130").clone())

На странице затирается почти весь html. С чем это может быть связано?

PS
Сама страница тут http://soyuz-pisatelei.ru/forum/104 код выполняю из консоли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в одной из ячеек которую вы вставляете скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.write('<a title="К последнему сообщению" class="forumLastPostLink" hr'+'ef="http://soyuz-pisatelei.ru/forum/104-6130-0-17">27.08.2013, 14:51</a>')
</script>
```

Он выполняется и переписывает все к чертям